# Searching out a pattern from Logs

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, grep, logs

The format of the logs is in this manner:

```
Junk Junk Junk : Junk Junk Junk:IP/Port Junk Junk
```

I want to search using the `IP` and the output should be only the `IP/Port` part of each line in that log file.

I tried out all possible combinations with `grep`, `cut` and `awk` and all that `bash` I know :D so is it possible? Or will I have to go on with some log parsing tools?

**Edit:** Please note that the format is not exactly the same, the position of `Junk:IP/Port` may change such that its not possible using `awk '{print $7}'`

**Update:** Adding a sample log

```
DATE NAME-FIREWALL : %RULE-NUM: Teardown TCP connection PKT-NUM for LAN1:X.X.X.X/XX to LAN2:X.X.X.X/XX duration 0:0:0 bytes XXXX TCP FINs
DATE NAME-FIREWALL : %RULE-NUM: Built inbound TCP connection PKT-NUM for LAN1:X.X.X.X/XX (X.X.X.X/XX) to LAN2:X.X.X.X/XX (X.X.X.X/XX)
```

And I need to search and get the IP/Port part alongside LAN2.

Comment: You are going to need to be a little more precise about what your input data looks like; paste a sample.

Comment: Do you need just the string `LAN2:X.X.X.X/XX` or the IP address:port in paretheses next to it as well?

Comment: @jasonwryan Just the `IP/Port` along the string `LAN2` i.e. `X.X.X.X/XX` from `LAN2:X.X.X.X/XX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i ~ /[^:]*:/ ) { n=split($i,A,":"); if (length(A[2]) && n==2) print A[2] ; }} ' b.txt
X.X.X.X/XX
X.X.X.X/XX
X.X.X.X/XX
X.X.X.X/XX
```

**Edit: (with LAN)**

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i ~ /[^:]*:/ ) { n=split($i,A,":"); if (length(A[2]) && n==2) printf "%s -- %s\n",A[1], A[2] ; }} ' b.txt
LAN1 -- X.X.X.X/XX
LAN2 -- X.X.X.X/XX
LAN1 -- X.X.X.X/XX
LAN2 -- X.X.X.X/XX
```

Comment: Gosh man how do you guys do that?? Lol just wow...Ok but that's not the full answer, but I guess I can manage the rest. You can check the comments below my question.

Comment: Hello, I've been using awk for a quater of a century, perl geek can make this code darker I guess.

Comment: I could use your answer because the LAN1 and LAN2 had different network ids. So I could simply `pipe` the output to `grep` and get the required one. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this one:

```
grep -Po 'LAN2:\K(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}/\d*' file
```

This looks for a block of `PATTERN:ipdigits.ipdigits.ipdigits.ipdigits/digits` and prints the `ipdigits.ipdigits.ipdigits.ipdigits/digits` part (`\K` "cleans" the matching). It indicates that `ipdigits` must have between 1 and 3 characters. More filters could be applied (to match 1 to 255).

#### Test

```
$ cat a
Junk Junk Junk : Junk Junk LAN2:123.123.2.2/56 Junk Junk
Junk Junk Junk : Junk Junk LAN3:22.33.44.55/22 Junk Junk
$ grep -Po 'LAN2:\K(\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}/\d*' a
123.123.2.2/56
```

Comment: eh, didnt work, I guess you didnt check the sample logs I updated.

Comment: Well it did not work because your sample log contains `X` instead of numbers for the IPs. How is your real input? If it does contain just `X`s, do `grep -Po 'LAN1:\K(\w{1,3}.){3}\w{1,3}/\w*' file`, or the same with `LAN2` or whatever.

Comment: Yes of-course the real logs do contain numbers i.e. IPs.

Comment: Then my code should make it. I tested with some IPs and it did. Let me know if it does not!